# Light OS alternative to Ubuntu

Tags: 12.04, vaio, overheating

I have asked a question https://askubuntu.com/questions/124119/has-the-ubuntu-heating-problem-for-sony-vaio-users-been-solved which didn't seem to get any answers, but I desperately want to use a *nix based operating system (to enhance my programming skills).

What *nix type OS should I use that is light, works for most important tasks of a programmer and at least has a browser, which doesn't cause (or shouldn't cause) heating problems for Sony-Vaio?

Comment: If you're interested in alternatives to Ubuntu that are either *not derivatives of Ubuntu* or *unofficial derivatives of Ubuntu*, that is probably beyond the scope of Ask Ubuntu, so you may want to ask about that on a more general site, such as [Unix.SE](http://unix.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: You seemed to have abandoned the question about the "Ubuntu heating problem". You were asked to run `top` when the temperature was high.

Comment: @EliahKagan I see your point, but it can be quite different between ubuntu distros. I had some terrible crashes with xubuntu and found with lubuntu although there were bugs they bugs were much less of a liability for my hardware set up than with the xubuntu distro happened to be at the time.

Comment: @vasa1 I didn't abandon it, there isn't much valuable information from top

Answer (score 3):

Try [Lubuntu](http://www.lubuntu.net). It is an official Ubuntu variant with the same support and packages. It uses LXDE so it is much more lightweight.

Comment: and better if I say so myself

Answer (score 2):

Echo the Lubuntu tip but one step further would be to get Lubuntu Core.

Lubuntu core is the lighest one; it is still Lubuntu, but with only the bare minimum packages pre-installed. That means, although you will have bits and bobs you need like a text editor and things like that, you won't have things like libre office bulking out your system.

You can add what you like after basic installation anyway. It does get all the Ubuntu repositories as standard but you can download the lubuntu specific ones from [here](http://ppa.launchpad.net/lubuntu-desktop/ppa/ubuntu).

and you can get the ppa by chucking that into terminal:

```
  sudo apt-add-repository ppa:lubuntu-desktop/ppa
  sudo apt-get update
```

Don't mind that it's called desktop. All the distros seem to be this way. Just bare in mind you will need to set it for a laptop on installation.

Answer (score 1):

The following links might help you:

- [What is the difference between Ubuntu and its derivatives?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/690/what-is-the-difference-between-ubuntu-and-its-derivatives)
- [What is the difference between the various Ubuntu flavours?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/152857/what-is-the-difference-between-the-various-ubuntu-flavours)