# Can I run Ubuntu applications in Xubuntu?

Tags: xubuntu

Can I run Ubuntu applications in Xubuntu? Are there any problems doing so? Can GNOME applications run in XFCE-based systems?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, both Ubuntu and Xubuntu use same repository. So, you can install and use gnome applications such as gnome-terminal in Xubuntu. But mind it, you can't use gnome-session in Xubuntu.

I myself used Xubuntu with gnome or Ubuntu applications, such as gnome-terminal, gedit etc. It's perfectly ok, unless you tried to run gnome or Ubuntu sessions on top of Xubuntu session.

Comment by the OP:

> So, I can even create programs using GTK, right? Using Anjuta or gEdit + GCC

Yes, of course. As long you installed the gtk libraries and necessary development tools.

- [What is the difference between the various Ubuntu flavours?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/152857/what-is-the-difference-between-the-various-ubuntu-flavours)
- [What is the difference between Ubuntu+XFCE and Xubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91380/what-is-the-difference-between-ubuntuxfce-and-xubuntu)

Comment: So, I can even create programs using GTK, right? Using Anjuta or gEdit + GCC?

Comment: Yes. if you have the necessary development tools installed

Comment: I used Ubuntu often, but not constantly. This Unity thingy is not for me. I love Xubuntu's XFCE interface. But, I don't have information about the difference of these desktop interfaces. What's the difference between Gnome and XFCE, like that. So, session is a problem. Why is that? What's the difference between gnome-terminal and xfce4-terminal? And there's a library called GTK for Gnome. Is there a library for XFCE? Thank you very much.

Comment: See the links above. gnome-terminal and xfce4-terminal basically same. but gnome-terminal has i think some more feature, looks good etc. And sessions isn't a problem if you don't have intension to use gnome or Unity

Comment: Thank you very much for your answers, Anwar. I may fall in love with you. It's nice to get some answers. I'll check those links after meal. Thank you very much.